# Best way to start learning Android development?

Tags: java, android

I want to start learning Android app development and was wondering whether I should start with an online school like treehouse or code academy (if so, which one would be the best) or just by using Google's tutorials. I have pretty decent knowledge with Java. I've never used an online school before, so I don't know how and what they teach. Which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: From the flagging options : "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._" **&&** "_Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too recently started learning Android Development and for me, I found that Big Nerd Ranch's book on Android Programming was extremely helpful. As someone who has had a lot of schooling in Java, there coding if very simplistic, but it is a great entry point into the subject IMO. During the 3 or 4 apps they walk you through, they gives you a good understand of, not only the development process of android apps, but also the Android SDK (development kit).

While Google's tutorials on android are very in-depth, BNR's book is much easier to swallow as a beginner.

Here's the link to their page if you're interested: http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/android-programming.html